# Unable to Encode a raw video in MV-HEVC

Tags: codec, hevc

I have a problem in encoding a raw multiview video in MV-HEVC codec,  I am facing  this error: "error parsing option frame 1 with argument". 
Any clue how to resolve this error?

Answer (score -1):

Replace in `source\Lib\TLibCommon\TypeDef.h`

```
#define HEVC_EXT    2
```

with

```
#define HEVC_EXT    1
```